# F# Order of Execution using CPS/Partial Application

Tags: f#, currying, continuations

Why does this print "DIV/0" first and "2" second?

```
let printZero = printfn "DIV/0"
let printSuccess x = printfn "%d" x

let div ifZero success x y =
    if y = 0
    then ifZero
    else x / y |> success

let printDiv = div printZero printSuccess
printDiv 8 4
printDiv 10 0
```

Comment: If you want printZero to behave as a function you must add unit as argument. let printZero () = ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printfn "DIV/0"` will write to the console immediately, returning `unit`.  So this line:

```
let printZero = printfn "DIV/0"
```

...will immediately write `DIV/0` and binds `unit` to the value `printZero`. Later when you call your `div` function with `y = 0`, you just return that value.

What you want is for `printZero` to be a function. As that function doesn't need any value as input, you can use `unit` here too (represented as `()`) - so you have a function of type `unit -> unit`:

```
let printZero() = printfn "DIV/0"
let printSuccess x = printfn "%d" x

let div ifZero success x y =
    if y = 0
    then ifZero()
    else x / y |> success
```